# SQL code in C# comparing attributes

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, compare

I've been working on a project in C# which at some point I need to compare two strings where their filename are the same,

```
SELECT Hash 
FROM Beamer.PackageDetailFile (NOLOCK) 
WHERE FileName = '"+fileName+"' ;
```

This is not working, table and column names are correct. However,

```
SELECT Hash FROM Beamer.PackageDetailFile (NOLOCK)
```

This code is giving me hashes.

What's the problem? Please help thanks.

Problem solved, the fileName im calling was the directory path not the filename, that was the problem. Works fine now cheers to all

Comment: Look at your keyboard. There is a key <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Try it. Very useful sometimes.

Comment: When you say not working what do you mean? does this give error messages or does the query return empty?  Also it is a really bad idea to create sql statements in c# by just joining to a string variable. It leaves your code open to injection attacks. It is good practice to get into the habit of using either stored procs or parameterized queries.

Comment: There are no errors, its just when i try to .read() it , it doesnt return anything, query just doesnt work

Comment: Sounds like the problem is data related then, most likely what you have in the filename variable doesnt match any records in the database.  Breakpoint your code and see what is in that variable, also try select everything from your table and check what is in there in the filename column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query itself *should* be fine, although it is very bad practice, and should use parameters, i.e.

```
WHERE FileName = @filename
```

and add a parameter to the command called `filename`, with the value from your local variable.

Reasons this can fail:

- case-sensitivity; if CS, then `'abc'` is not equal to `'AbC'` (if CI, *it is*)
- padding, i.e. `[n]char(len)` vs `[n]varchar(len)`; a `[n]char(len)` is padded with whitespace on the right, which can give odd results
- unicode, i.e. `N'{blah}'` vs `'{blah}'` - mainly only an issue for non-ASCII "blah"
- length trimming; if the column is `[n]varchar(20)` and your parameter is 80 characters long, it won't match the trimmed version in the column

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i am working on possible mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As people said, avoid creating sql statements in C#. But if you insist, check to make sure that the 'fileName' variable in C# is not empty and has the correct value.

Another issue that I ran into is that of the length of your column in SQL server. If your database column is varchar(50) for example, and your fileName is more than 50 characters, then the compare will fail (You will find that the filename stored in the database is truncated). In which case you should probably change your database column to a greater length or just varchar(max)

Comment: thanks for your answer, however that is not the possible mistake because the filenames and the ones in columns are mostly same, and also i dont have authorization to edit the database